# what it means : Multiple build commands for the images add in the iphone project?

Tags: iphone

when i compile my project it thorws warnings like :- Multiple build commands for the .png file

what does it means and how can we remove it ,Even i clean up my build xcode cache memory even than it is throwing this warning.

Hw can we remove this warning ?

Thanks 
Balraj

Answer (score 1):

You have two copies of the PNG file in your project, and you need to get rid of one.